# Tensorflow unrecognized arguments \\

Tags: tensorflow

Hi I am trying to create a tensorflow ImageClassifer following tensorflow-for-poets2 in codelab while i am trying to execute the following code

```
  python label_image.py \ -- 
    graph=C:\Python_PG\ImageClassifier\poets\tf_files\retrained_graph.pb \ -- 
    image=C:\TensorFlow_ML\ImageClassifier\poets\tf_files\3021186b83bc90c2.png
```

I am getting the following error

```
usage: label_image.py [-h] [--image IMAGE] [--graph GRAPH] [--labels LABELS]
                      [--input_height INPUT_HEIGHT]
                      [--input_width INPUT_WIDTH] [--input_mean INPUT_MEAN]
                      [--input_std INPUT_STD] [--input_layer INPUT_LAYER]
                      [--output_layer OUTPUT_LAYER]
label_image.py: error: unrecognized arguments: \ \
```

I am using windows os.Please help me resolve this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer by @jaboja is surely correct. In general, when a command-line program responds with `Usage:`, then it is complaining that you have not supplied its arguments in the correct format.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** Write the command in a single line, without the line break escape sequences.

---

**Longer answer:**
The error says exactly what you are doing wrong: you typed something that was just a line break escape sequence in tutorial as an unrecognized argument for your command.

You can of course break line inside the command, as in the tutorial. But you are adding a " -- " (i.e. space, dash, dash, space) and this makes your "\" not a line break but just one of arguments. You need to either place the "\" just before the line break (no spaces nor dashes before) or just abandon the line breaks and "\" altogether and just type the whole command in one line.

By the way, its not a Tensorflow or Python related. It's how BASH works.

And there you may have one more problem: if you are not using BASH (and Windows paths suggest you may be using CMD.EXE instead, unless you use something like git-bash) the escape sequence may be different, i.e. ^ character in case of Windows command line. More about that:

https://superuser.com/questions/150116/how-can-i-insert-a-new-line-in-a-cmd-exe-command

ps. And of course the param syntax is “--graph=…”, not “--*<new line + several spaces>*graph=…”.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar error in my code-

```
!python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py \
    --graph = model_output/graph_v1.pb \
    --labels = model_output/labels_v1.txt \
    --input_layer='input' --output_layer='final_result' \
    --input_height=224 --input_width=224 \
    --image=path/13.jpg

label_image.py: error: unrecognized arguments: model_output/graph_v1.pb model_output/labels_v1.txt
```

You do not add spaces before and after '=' sign.

```
!python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py \
    --graph=model_output/graph_v1.pb \
    --labels=model_output/labels_v1.txt \
    --input_layer='input' --output_layer='final_result' \
    --input_height=224 --input_width=224 \
    --image=path/13.jpg
```